# Should using a temporary docker container remove a volume?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Running a docker container with the `--rm` option deletes a mounted volume post exit.  I'm wondering whether this is intended behavior?

Here is the exact sequence.

```
ole@MKI:~$ docker volume create --name a-volume-test

ole@MKI:~$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/ | grep a-
a-volume-test

ole@MKI:~$ docker run --rm -it -v a-volume-test:/data alpine /bin/ash
/ # touch /data/test
/ # ls /data
test
/ # exit

ole@MKI:~$ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/ | grep a-
```

After I exit the the volume is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that will be fixed in docker 1.11 - https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19568

Answer (score 2):

According to the Docs, no that is not intended, because you are mounting a named volume it should not be deleted. Maybe submit a github issue?

> Note: When you set the `--rm` flag, Docker also removes the volumes associated with the container when the container is removed. This is similar to running `docker rm -v my-container`. Only volumes that are specified without a name are removed. For example, with `docker run --rm -v /foo -v awesome:/bar busybox top`, the volume for `/foo` will be removed, but the volume for `/bar` will not. Volumes inheritted via `--volumes-from` will be removed with the same logic -- if the original volume was specified with a name it will not be removed.

[Source: Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)